# Calculate the integral with branches

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts

I need to calculate the following integral

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1+z)^{1/4}(1-z)^{3/4}}{1+z}\, dz$$

I know how to do it by real-analysis method but I am supposed to  use Cauchy theorem. But the residues at $z=-1$ and $\infty$ are zero. Am I doing something wrong with the branches?

Comment: Can you show a bit more work? How are you calculating residues? What are your branch points? What’s your branch cut/arguments?

Comment: I had a branch cut line goes from -1 to 1 on the real axis so i integrated x+i0 and x-i0 above and beneath this line. Point z=-1 is a simple 1 order pole, so to calculate the residue I calculated lim (z+1)f(z) as z goes to -1 also for inf. And they are both zero (I even checked on wolfram alpha), isn't it?

Comment: You could make things a bit easier by substituting$$w=\frac{1-z}{1+z}\implies\int_0^\infty\frac{2w^{3/4}}{(1+w)^2}\,dw$$and integrate along a keyhole contour.

Comment: @user170231 Oh, yes! Thank you! You saved my day! It was so obvious, but I didn't get it. But anyway I would be happy to know why straight calculation went wrong.

Comment: Even the antiderivative is simple

Comment: If you want to use complex integration, the bigbone contour (around the cut $(-1;1)$) is appropriate. Denoting 
$$I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1+z)^{1/4}(1-z)^{3/4}}{1+z}\, dz=\int_{-1}^1(1+z)^{-3/4}(1-z)^{3/4}\, dz$$
you first show that the integral along the bigbone contour (clockwise)
$$I_C=\oint_C(1+z)^{-3/4}(1-z)^{3/4}\, dz=I(1-i)$$
then deform the contour into a circle of the radius $R\to\infty$ and evaluate the residue at infinity. You will get
$$I(1-i)=3\pi i\,e^{-\frac{3\pi i}4}$$